# c# async socket via interface

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, event-handling

Bear with me here and try and go easy on bad practice :)

I am beginning to understand the concept of interfaces and I have implemented one in my program.. So I'll try and explain.. I am creating a class library dll that will interface with my alarm panel. The alarm panel can have two types of connection, IP and Serial.. So I have implemented an interface for this called IConnection.

and create a connection as follows:

```
//IConnection connection = new SerialConnection("com1", 9600);
IConnection conn = new TcpConnection(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.14"), 1234);

AlarmPanel alarm = new AlarmPanel(conn, Pass);
alarm.SetLogger(logger);
alarm.Connect();
```

in the concrete class (correct terminology?) I implement a method called SendMessage which I use to be transport agnostic which is working well.

However I now want to add a async handler to process adhoc messages sent back that aren't command/response style messages.

I have an eventhandler working in my main TCPConnection Class:

```
   private static void tcpReceive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject {workSocket = client};

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void receiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead <= 0) return; // No data...

            // Console.WriteLine("Ascii {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            Console.WriteLine("Raw: {0}", BitConverter.ToString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            processMessage(new Response {Data = state.buffer,BytesLength = bytesRead} );

            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), state);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void processMessage(Response resp)
    {
       // Do something with the message here.. 
    }
```

However I want to abstract the IP stuff from the processing code and move the processMessage back up into my Class which uses the interface.. (I know I not explaining this well.. so let me re-try)

Set up event handler in my "class TcpConnection : IConnection"

Turn on event handling from AlarmPanel Class which the constructor looks like:

```
public AlarmPanel(IConnection connection, int Password)
    {
        _connection = connection;
        _Password = Password;
    }
```

which uses that interface  (IConnection), and be able to say use the ProcessMessage method from the alarmPanel Class,  so that I can then call the same method for when I get the serial event handling working..

Comment: You are using multiple layer of networking (7 layers).  You have an application layer processing messages and a transportation layer (serial or TCP).  Your messages need  to contain type of message so your application layer know the what to do with the messages.   So you want all receive message handled as async even though some are master slave and others adhoc.  I usually send all message using sync methods.  I would start by defining all the messages type.  The application layer will have a message queue where the send messages will be matched with the response and will allow adhoc to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to register an event on your interface `IConnection`, which `AlarmPanel` can subscribe to. This way you can let the `IConnection` implementation handle the logic for retrieving the message, but let `AlarmPanel` do what it wants with the recieved message.

```
public class AlarmPanel
{
    public AlarmPanel(IConnection connection, int Password)
    {
        _connection = connection;
        _Password = Password;
        // Bind event.
        _connection.MessageReceived += ProcessMessage;
    }

    private void ProcessMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do your central processing here with e.Message.
    }
}

public interface IConnection
{
    event Action<object, MessageEventArgs> MessageRecieved;
}

public class TcpConnection : IConnection
{
    // Other code.

    private static void processMessage(Response resp)
    {
       // Do something with the message here..
       var eventArgs = new MessageEventArgs
       {
           Message = response
       };
       OnMessageReceived(eventArgs);
    }

    protected virtual void OnMessageReceived(MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call subscribers.
        var handler = MessageRecieved;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }
    public event Action<object, MessageEventArgs> MessageRecieved;
}

// Class for passing Response back to AlarmPanel.
public class MessageEventArgs : System.EventArgs
{
    Response Message { get; set; } // Consider using an interface for Response.
}
```

Comment: That sounds right and looks like the correct interpretation of my post, Thankyou, I will try this and let you know the outcome.

Comment: Cool. Let me know if there's anything I can clarify.

Comment: I finally got around to testing this and it worked fine, thanks :)